# How to tell if there are single quote or double quote marks in a string in r

Tags: r, quote

How to tell if there are single quote or double quote marks in a string in r.

Here is my object:

```
test_object_1 <- "test_1"
```

I want to use `grepl('"', test_object_1)` to see if there are quotes in the `test_object`.

When I do so, I get this:

```
> grepl('"', test_object_1)
[1] FALSE
```

I want it to say `TRUE`, not `FALSE`.

Here is the single quote mark version

```
> test_object_2 <- 'test_2'
> 
> grepl("'", test_object_2)
[1] FALSE
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Try `test_object_1 <- '"hello"'` or `test_object_1 <- "'hello'"` instead. `grepl('"', test_object_1)` and `grepl("'", test_object_1)` should work then. Edit : wrong quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single or double quote in either `test_object_1` or `test_object_2`. R chooses to display strings always with double quotes.

If you use `cat` you'll see the "real" string.

```
cat(test_object_1)
#test_1
```

To insert double quotes in the string you can do -

```
test_object_1 <- "\"test_1\""
#Or
#test_object_1 <- '"test_1"'

#[1] "\"test_1\""

cat(test_object_1)
#"test_1"
```